# Working in an agency, can I put in our clients' company on my LinkedIn profile?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, linkedin

I am a Web Developer and I work in agency where they give us clients from other agencies/companies to work with. Can I put in our clients' company on my `LinkedIn` profile? If not, can I put it as a `Project` instead?

Scenario: I was adding a colleague from another Web Development agency that I'm working with, and I'd like to add him as `colleague` but `LinkedIn` is asking which company did we work together on. Since basically they are our clients I thought of putting their company's name in the field but I'm not sure whether it'd be cool for both agencies.

Answer (score 2):

If the company doesn't have any problem with that, then you can add the project.

They wouldn't really have a problem with you listing them in the summary as *worked with* as client.

However, you need to take permission before putting the projects, as some of them might be stealth or internal projects, which they might not be ready to release or are being developed as a one-up against their competitors. So, in that case, you'd be letting them down if you make that project public.

Comment: Thanks! That actually make sense. But which company are you referring to that I should get permission from? The one I'm hired in or our Client's? Or both?

Comment: @JohnnyQ I meant the clients. If the clients don't have a problem, then your employer also shouldn't, logically. :)

Comment: I'll try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: You should get the approval of both your company and the client before listing the specifics of the work you're doing. Both companies may have competitive reasons for keeping things quiet for a time. Your social media activity can have an effect on your employer, especially LinkedIn, so you should not feel completely free to post whatever you want.

Comment: Check your company's written policies as well. The company I work for specifically prohibits all references to clients by name in any social media.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is NDA. In my current company, I'm only allowed to list about half of the clients I've worked with from a legal perspective. Next, you should make sure that your company handbook does not directly or indirectly prohibit you from posting to LinkedIn about your work with the client – it may be against your own firms rules.

When it comes to my résumé as well as LinkedIn, I generally put the name of the company I work for, and then include the client in the description of one or more of the tasks I worked on. So, for example:

### Parse3 Communications (2012)

- Created the Nair product selection tool for Church and Dwight

The reason I generally prefer this format is because while I did do work for Church and Dwight, I did not answer up their hierarchy and my performance was not evaluated by their company.

You also don't want anything on LinkedIn which can be considered misleading. An HR person might ask questions, or might have even formerly worked at the company. Saying, "well, technically I didn't work for them" does not come across well.

Comment: Makes sense actually. I'll consider that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this in the past.  When LinkedIn asks how you know them, use the colleague option and select your employer.  This is the truth, you are their colleague and it is through your current employer.  Also, as far as I know, this process is just a safeguard to keep people from adding people they don't know and shouldn't affect your connection on LinkedIn.

Comment: Exactly. But the problem is when you fill that field it will automatically gets added on your profile.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer, use your employer and not the client.  Then this won't be an issue because, presumably, you already have your employer on your profile.

Comment: But what if your colleague is unaware of your company/employer? Scenario: I was working with this colleague for a week for turn over activities and is leaving his current company and our company is taking over his work. I'm not sure if he is aware of which company I'm working, I would understand, if I'm in his position all I would care about is that I am handling a new job, with better pay, plus if your wife is giving birth within that week, etc.

Comment: Well if he doesn't know your company, he probably knows your name or your face.  If he doesn't know your company, your name, or your face then you shouldn't really expect them to accept your connection.